# Should we cache error responses in REST API

Tags: rest, caching, cdn

Is it a good practice to cache error responses in the REST API?

Having a heavy loaded application exposing REST API and hidden behind CDN we are currently caching status 200 responses on the CDN but anything other than 200 is not being cached thus increasing the load considerably.

The nature of the application is such that 404 responses are expected to occur often. Shall we then cache error responses on the CDN also, with different expiration policy perhaps? Is it a good practice in your opinion or according to REST standard?

Thank You!

Comment: Do you expect the resources that are `404`ing to ever be available again? If not, it's probably fine. If the 404 is temporary, it may still be okay, but it gets more complicated.

Comment: Rob, I am expecting them to be available again. Why does it get more complicated in such case? I thought of shorter expiration times for errors.

Comment: Shorter `Expires` may help, but also consider that if a client gets a resource URL from you and immediately turns around and does a `GET` request on it, but receives a `404`, that may be strange from the client perspective. If that behavior is okay, then expiring the cache is probably fine. But you may want to explicitly invalidate caches if you know when resources are available again.